# how to access subelement of a specific element in elementtree database from an xml file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file which looks like:

```
<Cars>
    <Car vin="1" 
        label="Ford"    
        <features>
            layout="hatchback"
            color="red"
        </features>                      
    </Car>
    <Car vin="2" 
        label="GM"  
        <features>
            layout="4door"
            color="blue"
        </features>                      
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

i would like to get the features subelement of the car with vin==2:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(xmlFile)
root = tree.getroot()
for car in root.findall("Car"):
`  vin = car.get("vin")

   features = list()
   if vin == "2":
      features = car.find("features")
      color = features.get("color")
      print("color is {}".format(color))
```

but the code does not work. it seemingly can not find the subelement "features"

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no error. color = features.get("color") just returns a value of None for color

Comment: ok. i figured out the issue. it is my fault. there is syntax error in the xml file. now it works.

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, you should [(and are encouraged to)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) include the solution as an answer to your question. This is so you can help others that come across the same issue later on.

Comment: the original xml file has syntax flaws. the correct version should be the following:

Answer (score 1):

the python code is correct but the original xml file has syntax flaws. the correct version should be the following(the location of closing bracket '>' for attributes) :

```
<Cars>
    <Car vin="1" 
        label="Ford" >   
        <features
            layout="hatchback"
            color="red">
        </features>                      
    </Car>
    <Car vin="2" 
        label="GM"> 
        <features
            layout="4door"
            color="blue">
        </features>                      
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

obviously elementtree parses it silently.